# Days calculation between two dates flex Wave Analytics

Tags: einstein-analytics

I want to calculate the days between two dates from 2009 to till now in Flex Wave analytics.

I am referring this link(https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_saql.meta/bi_dev_guide_saql/bi_saql_functions_date.htm) but it is not working for me.

I have a query--

```
q = load "0Fb6F000000HTubSAG/0Fc6F000000HbrGSAS";
q = group q by ('CreatedDate_Year', 'CreatedDate_Month');
q = foreach q generate 'CreatedDate_Year' + "~~~" + 'CreatedDate_Month' as 'CreatedDate_Year~~~CreatedDate_Month', unique('Id') as 'unique_Id';
q = order q by 'CreatedDate_Year~~~CreatedDate_Month' asc;
q = limit q 2000;
```

where to put the date function in this?

Thanks
Tanushree Roy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    q = foreach q generate daysBetween
(toDate('CreatedDate_Year'+ \"-\"+ CreatedDate_Month + \"-\" 
+ CreatedDate_Day, \"yyyy-MM-dd\"),now()) as age
```

Answer (score 1):

The response provided is not wrong, however when updating the generate statement in the SAQL editor the statement should be:

```
    generate daysBetween(toDate('CreatedDate_Year'+"-"+'CreatedDate_Month'+"-"
+'CreatedDate_Day', "yyyy-MM-dd"),now()) as age;
```

Comment: q foreach q generate daysBetween(toDate('CreatedDate_Year'+"-"+'CreatedDate_Month'+"-"+'CreatedDate_Day', "yyyy-MM-dd"),now()) as age

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post to add any information you wish. Comments are not designed for that purpose.